# get page name from button through jquery on external js file

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is there a way to get name of aspx page the button belongs to on its onclient click function in external JavaScript file .I don’t want to pass string to the function and check as the same function has no parameters and don’t want to add either as its used elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) property within your function.

external.js

```
function doSomething() {
    alert(window.location.pathname);
}
```

In the .aspx file

```
<script src="external.js"></script>
<asp:button id="Button1" onclientclick="doSomething()">
```